# Receiving the same pandas output twice in Python IDLE

Tags: python, pandas

When I run a simple python code in IDLE (or directly in Windows command prompt by typing "python filename.py") everything goes as expected, e.g.

```
print("hello")
```

gives me the following output:

```
hello
```

However when I use pandas with a dataframe, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':['John','Tom','Luke','Mike'],
  'Height':[180,178,182,179],
  'Weight':[80,75,72,86],}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

I receive the expected output but always twice:

```
==================== RESTART: C:\Users\t\OneDrive\c\py.py ====================
   Height  Name  Weight
0     180  John      80
1     178   Tom      75
2     182  Luke      72
3     179  Mike      86
   Height  Name  Weight
0     180  John      80
1     178   Tom      75
2     182  Luke      72
3     179  Mike      86
>>>
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Just a hunch, could the assingment `df = ` be printing the assignment? If you do `x=[1,2,3]`, is the list printed? Conversely, delete the print statement - does it still print?

Comment: `df =` is not printing anything on its own.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce. Any chance you do a little more than `import,data=,df=,print` in IDLE? Otherwise hopefully someone else knows the answer.

Comment: The four commands you mentioned are the only ones I have. The code in the OP is the entire code. I don't even know where to start looking, seems to be something under the hood

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you saved your script with the same name as the imported module, 'pandas.py', and it imports itself.